# Flatpak Libreoffice has blank icons in dock/dash

Tags: icons, libreoffice, flatpak

I installed LibreOffice as a Flatpak in Ubuntu 18.04. The same behavior was observed with the Snap version.

When I open a Writer or a Calc file the icon in the GNOME dash (vertical dock bar on the left) is just blank.

[image]

How to see again the LibreOffice icons (Writer, Calc, etc.)?